# Entity framework con oracle developer. Validar el usuario

Tags: c#, oracle-sqldeveloper

//Evento del Botón

```
protected void LoginButton_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   bool existe;

   string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USUARIO WHERE login= :p_login AND password= :p_password ";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":p_login", OracleType.VarChar).Value = this.Login1.UserName.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":p_password", OracleType.VarChar).Value = this.Login1.Password.ToString();

    //int valor = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());


    using (EntitiesOracle context = new EntitiesOracle())
    {
        existe = db.Usuarios.Any(x => x.DNI = dni && x.password = password);
    }

    if (existe)
    {
        //pasa la autenticacion
    }
}
```

PREGUNTA: que le hace falta o es mejor implementarlo con un procedure?
agradezco su ayuda gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que hace falta para que? y que es lo que preguntas si es mejor hacerlo con un procedure. De por si te diria que si esas pass no estan encriptadas es un grave problema de seguridad.

Answer (score 0):

basado en opiniones, pero en su mayoría de las veces o todas siempre es mejor tener el código de SQL en stored procedures y funciones por varios motivos

1. Tiempo de compilación

   > Los store procedures ya están compilados, por lo que únicamente esperan parámetros para ejecutarse, codificando la consulta directamente en código hará que cada vez que e invoque se tenga que recompilar
2. Visibilidad del Código

   > Esto depende si quieres que los desarrolladores quieres que vean las consultas de SQL que estas ejecutando, normalmente lo único que el desarrollador necesita es saber los parámetros de entrada y los resultados, el resto esta a discreción de los DBA
3. Control de Código

   > y este es el mas importante, **NO QUIERES DARLE MANTENIMIENTO A LOS CAMBIOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS EN EL CÓDIGO DE TU APLICACIÓN**(pondría esto en rojo si pudiera)
   >   El principal problema de  tener esto así es que si necesitas hacerle cambios a la consulta deberás de hacerlo directamente desde el código de tu app y esto requiere compilar y redistribuir tu ejecutable, si la consulta vive en un store procedure solo necesitas cambiarlo desde tu base de datos y mientras los parámetros de entrada y salida sigan siendo los mismos entonces no tendrás que modificar la aplicación original